# cannot construct the infinite type: e ~ [e]

Tags: haskell

Why this code:

```
a=array ((0,0),(5,5)) [((i,j),x) | i <- [0..5], j <- [0..5], x <- a!(i,j)]
```

cause error `cannot construct the infinite type: e ~ [e]`,
but if rewrite it like this:

```
a=array ((0,0),(5,5)) [((i,j),a!(i,j)) | i <- [0..5], j <- [0..5]]
```

it works fine?

Comment: I think you are aware that the last definition fills the array with non-terminating computations, but I wanted to point that out just in case.

Comment: @chi, This is only minimal senseless example of the problem, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a list comprehension, the right side of `<-` is a *list* to take elements from.  But you can use `let` expressions:

```
[ ... | ..., let x = a ! (i,j) ]
```